# Read a txt file and then use the first row data as a parameter to create a bidimensional array (c#)

Tags: c#

i have the following txt, this are the first 10 rows of 211 total,the numbers are saparated by spaces and only the first row is diferent because it will only be used to know the size of the bidimensional array, the other 210 rows are similar because they will be saved in the bidimensional array

```
210 7
15.26   14.84   0.871   5.763   3.312   2.221   5.22
14.88   14.57   0.8811  5.554   3.333   1.018   4.956
14.29   14.09   0.905   5.291   3.337   2.699   4.825
13.84   13.94   0.8955  5.324   3.379   2.259   4.805
16.14   14.99   0.9034  5.658   3.562   1.355   5.175
14.38   14.21   0.8951  5.386   3.312   2.462   4.956
14.69   14.49   0.8799  5.563   3.259   3.586   5.219
14.11   14.1    0.8911  5.42    3.302   2.7 5
16.63   15.46   0.8747  6.053   3.465   2.04    5.877
```

i need to create a  bidimensional array using the first row data as a parameter 210 rows and 7 columns (this parameters could change like this 210 6 or 100 4) and then save the other rows in the bidimensional array.

i had this code in c++ and  i  just need the matrix to continue  so can you please help me  this was my old code

```
ifstream database;
database.open("irisdata.txt");

if(database.fail())
{
    cout<<"error";
    getch();
    exit(0);
}
database>>fil>>col;
for(int i=0;i<fil;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<col;j++)
    {
        database>>a[i][j];

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean a matrix? and what do you mean the first column is different and the others are the same?

Comment: by matrix i mean 2dimensional array and  i mean that the first column contains 2 rows and the others 7 rows

Comment: Here is how to create the array: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18806757/495455

Answer (score 0):

Try following assuming there is only one group of inputs that start at beginning of file :

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            string inputline = "";

            List<List<decimal>> data = new List<List<decimal>>();
            int columns = 0;
            int dataPoints = 0;
            Boolean firstRow = true;

            string[] inputArray;

            while ((inputline = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                inputline = inputline.Trim();
                if (inputline.Length > 0)
                {
                    inputArray = inputline.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToArray();
                    if (firstRow == true)
                    {
                        firstRow = false;
                        dataPoints = int.Parse(inputArray[0]);
                        columns = int.Parse(inputArray[1]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        List<decimal> inputDecimal = inputArray.Select(x => decimal.Parse(x)).ToList();
                        data.Add(inputDecimal);
                    }
                }
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry to bother you but by matrix i mean bidimensional array

Comment: A List<List<int>> is a two dimensional array.  A List is just an array with enhanced methods.